# CSS icon toolkit containing car logos

Tags: gratis, web-apps, web

Is there something like font awesome containing a list of item icons, like car logos and tv brands and stuff like that? Most importantly car logos like BMW etc.

Comment: Company brand logos are generally trademarked, so you're unlikely to find a legal resource containing large numbers of them (since you'd need an agreement with each company to use their trademarks).

Comment: @BrenBarn ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh yes good note! thank you